# How to change screen resolution on OS X

Tags: resolution, osx-mountain-lion

I am a noob to OS X (coming from Ubuntu/Centos) and am unable to locate the system settings app used for selecting resolution. I looked at the "displays" and it was not there. I am using Mountain Lion 10.8.3.   I have retina display.

UPDATE:  my confusion is having seen what turns out to be a THIRD PARTY app called QuickRes. I was looking for that believing it be part of native MacOS.  QuickRes is doing what I want and have changed to 2880x1800

Comment: Apple tries to tell you what is best with that (I am on one too and was confused as well).  Some tips that may be helpful can be found [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5266).

Comment: To add onto my comment, do you have the `Retina` or traditional display?  If you have the retina, then choosing `Scaled` yields options that aren't specific to resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the [apple answer](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5369)

The option is under displays and by default OSX decides your screen resolution. However you can change it manually.

Coming from a linux background that might all sound very illogical but most OSX wouldn't see a point in lowering there screen resolution

Comment: i wanted to increase the resolution to 2800x1800.  As noted in OP i found out the QuickRes 3rd party is what I am seeking.

Comment: Didn't see that before hand - as a linux guy you can also edit /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist file to <key>Graphics Mode</key><string>2800x1800x32@60</string>

Answer (score 2):

Under Display, change from 'Best fit for built in display' to 'scaled'

[image]

Comment: That depends on if they're using the "Retina" display vs. traditional, mine is a retina which doesn't provide the same options. I'd give an image, but Imgur says it's over capacity right now...

Answer (score 1):

The option may not exist for your primary monitor, if you are on a `Retina` branded device, then the option doesn't exist.  Here is a screenshot of my 15"

[image]

As you can see, it's either the default (high res/dpi) or options to adjust the way it looks somewhat (probably technically different resolutions, but not labeled as such).

If you have a nonRetina display, then @Spuder's answer should get you there.

Note, when I have an external display attached - in this same menu I do have the resolution options for the external displays.